# Why does a zoo object sometimes have dimensions and sometimes doesn't?

Tags: r, zoo

I am trying to figure out why zoo objects sometimes have dimensions and sometimes they don't. Suppose I have:

```
x.dates <-c(as.Date('2018-01-01'), as.Date('2018-01-02'))
x <- rnorm(2)
y <- rnorm(2)
z1 <- zoo(x, x.dates)
z2 <- zoo(y, x.dates)
```

Why does the following return NULL:

```
dim(z1)
dim(z2)
```

but the following HAS Dimensions:

```
dim(merge(z1, z2))
```

How can I tune/tweak this to make both cases have dimensions? i.e. both cases to behave consistently.

Comment: @RichScriven I could use `merge.zoo` and that has the same effect as `merge` so I don't think the fact that merge is converting it to a `data.frame` has any bearing on the issue.

Comment: `merge` will use `merge.zoo` for `zoo` objects. See `methods(merge)`

Comment: why the negative votes?

Comment: `x` and `y` do *not* have dimensions so there is no reason to expect that `z1` and `z2`  have dimensions.  As @Rich Scriven points out `zoo(cbind(x), x.dates)` has dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure what you're asking for here, but you can run `cbind` on your individual `zoo` vectors, then they will have dimensions and remain as `zoo` classed objects.

```
cbind(z1)
#                     z1
# 2018-01-01  0.18104641
# 2018-01-02 -0.08397933

cbind(z2)
#                   z2
# 2018-01-01 1.6893870
# 2018-01-02 0.3941877

class(cbind(z1))
# [1] "zoo"
class(cbind(z2))
# [1] "zoo"
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I was looking for!